# UIImageView under UITableView does not show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I want to add a UIImageView under a UITableView, using the following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView = ({
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableView;
});


self.waterMarkImageView = ({
        UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        imageView.alpha = 1.0;
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"waterMark"];
        imageView;
});

[self.view addSubview:self.waterMarkImageView];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
[self.waterMarkImageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make){
       make.right.equalTo(self.view.mas_right);
       make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_bottom);
       make.width.equalTo(self.view.mas_width);
       make.height.equalTo(self.view.mas_height);
   }];

[self.tableView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make){
       make.top.equalTo(self.view.mas_top).offset(statusBarHeight + navigationBarHeight + labelHeight);
       make.left.equalTo(self.view.mas_left);
       make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_bottom);
       make.right.equalTo(self.view.mas_right);
   }];
```

However there is no waterMarkImageView shows.
But if I exchange the order that I add waterMarkImageView and tableView to the subviews of self.view, that is:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
[self.view addSubview:self.waterMarkImageView];
```

Then the waterMarkImageView will show, but above the tableview, that will cover a part of the tableview and that isn't what I expect. Anyone knows how to deal with this problem?

Well sorry actually from the view hierarchy I can see a part of the watermark, not the whole. And when I run the app I can see nothing.

Comment: try waterMarkImage.alpha=0.6;

Comment: @KishoreKumar, I do not think that your suggestion will help (though I may be wrong) because the OP's issue is not the transparency of the image, but rather the transparency of what is *covering* the image (I.e. The tableView).

Comment: It doesn't work :( Only a part of the water mark shows in view hierarchy, and nothing shows when I run the app

Comment: @Dopapp Oh when I set the background color of cell itself it works. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot see the imageView because it is *behind* the tableView. This makes sense as you added the tableView *after* the imageView. To fix this, simply set the background color of the cells to clearColor(). This will make them transparent so that you can see the imageView that is behind them.